# How can i get bluetooth devices array with python (for windows)?

Tags: python, windows, web, bluetooth

How can i get bluetooth devices array with python (for windows)?
Almost all libraries are for linux. But i need to use windows. İf you know python bluetooth libraries and methods can you suggest me? Especially i need to get a devices array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pybluez](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez)
Example code for basic start:

```py
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

Example code from github:

```py
# bluetooth low energy scan
from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService

service = DiscoveryService()
devices = service.discover(2)

for address, name in devices.items():
    print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

Also you can use [bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak). Example code:

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank You! I'm having problems with pybluez because it's for linux and windows xp,7,8,10. I am using windows 11. But i will try. Thank you again !

Comment: Can you please try this library: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak

Comment: Thank you very much i think i will solve my problem with this library. Thank you again ! Have a good days!

Comment: Added working solution and example code  to answer you can mark as answer.